# DIrectX 12 and D3D12CreateDevice fail

Tags: c++, windows, directx-12

I'm trying to run microsoft DirectX12 code samples but in every case the function D3D12CreateDevice fails. I compiled code with Visual Studio 2015 and the WIndows SDK.
I have a GTX560Ti, my driver is 353.62 for Windows 10. On the NVidia panel it's written current directX version 12 but on the dxdiag panel it's written 11.2 . I think that the problem is here...
How to solve the problem and run directX code ?

Comment: Your card should support DX12. What is the error code that CreateDevice returns?

Comment: The error is 0x887a0004 : The requested functionality is not supported by the device or the driver.

Comment: I had a similar problem. My card is GTX 460M. It's now Aug 2016, but it seems DirectX 12 is not yet supported. I installed driver 372.54, and Windows 10 Anniversary Update. 

dxdiag reports DirectX 12. Nvidia control panel reports DirectX 12 runtime, but Direct3D API version is still 11.2. I suspect this causes D3D12CreateDevice failed. Anyone with solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GTX 560 Ti is a "Fermi" based Nvidia GPU. Fermi GPUs are not yet supported by Nvidia's drivers for D3D12; support will be coming later this year.

http://www.anandtech.com/show/9472/windows-10-launch-day-gpu-support-summary